# import multi csvs into R based on number of rows

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have a folder of (mostly) csvs that I want to read into R and then bind together. However, I only want to import csvs with 641 rows. This is data from my experiment, so any CSVs that have fewer rows or are NULL means the participant abandoned the study and thus I do not want to include them.

```
#lists all csv files in folder
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv", recursive = T)

# initialize empty object 
pdm_dat <- NULL

#loop through files, import, concatenate
for(file in files){
  print(file)
  jj <- read.csv(file, sep = ",", header = T)
  print(nrow(jj))
  pdm_dat <- rbind.fill(pdm_dat, jj)
}
```

But I get an error because one of the CSVs is empty `(read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : no lines available in input. )`

So, how do I loop through files and only import the ones with 641 rows?

I tried to do something like this, but the result is a list of length 139 where each list is just the number of rows of that file, could I use that as a condition in the for loop? :

```
y<-lapply(X = files, FUN = function(x) {
  length(count.fields(x, skip = 1))
})
```

Sorry I know this is probably an easy question, I’m new to R. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\..csv$", recursive = TRUE)

Filter(length, lapply(files, function(x) {
  tmp <- tryCatch(read.csv(x), error = function(e) return(NA))
  if(NROW(tmp) == 641) tmp else NULL
})) -> combine_data
```

Comment: I think I might be implementing it incorrectly, I still get this error: `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : no lines available in input`

Comment: Check `files` are those all csvs that you want to read? Are there any files included there which is not a csv? Maybe try using `files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: All the 139 CSVs are listed (not filtered), like so: `> files
  [1] "132241_newbreak_2021-02-13_13h20.43.508.csv"                                                       
  [2] "140206_newbreak_2021-02-09_22h57.22.567.csv"` etc. I tried your code, but my files did not change (I think they are all listed just fine though, no other file types there).

Comment: I included `tryCatch` to handle files that are empty. Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: Yes, it works!! Every relevant data frame is in a list, now I'll try to combine them all together. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can do `combine_data <- do.call(rbind, combine_data)` to get dataframes together.